# Create a dynamic HTML template and feed data

Tags: html, dynamic-html

Want to create dynamic template for a feed and feed data into it. Data consists of title, image url, subtitle, content, etc.

How do I create a dynamic template and how to feed data into it?

Edit: I wanted to create a news feed type like webpage. I can use jQuery. I have data coming from a link in JSON format. I tried with appending to tables. But that didn't seem like the correct way out. Is there a dynamic way to do so?

Comment: You should use any JS framework that can able to generate dynamic component. like angular, react etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can not create dynamic webpages using **only** `HTML`. You have to pick a programming language to feed your data to your static template, which can be built on `html`

Comment: Question Editted.